# How to stop bouncing (Swipe) TTLauncherView

Tags: iphone, ios5, ttlauncherview

in my app i made a `TTLauncherView` which has 9 icons. Now client want that these all 9 icon **will not swipe** and will look fixed at swiping because they are not going to vary.
I can do this simply replacing `TTLaunchView` with 9 static buttons but i dont want to spoil the current code.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done :-)

Go to your class where you made object of `TTLauncherView`. Now right click on `TTLauncherView` and select **Jump To definition** (or just hold the command key and click on `TTLauncherView` for iOS 5). This will bring you to `TTLauncherView.m` file (class). Now find `_scrollView.alwaysBounceHosrizontal = YES;` Make this `YES` to `NO`, Thats it :-)

donno how i forgot that `TTLauncherView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. ;-)